# Failed to insert first record from foreach

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli, foreach

I'm having a problem with the foreach loop which is not isnerting first record in DB while I can see it print's out all the records.

This is the code I'm using:

```
            //Now we get costs in% and absolute
        $number = 0;
        $numberText = "";
        $numberName = "";
        foreach($cost_array as $key => $value){
          //Here we select only costs with % so we could calculate percentage
          if(strcmp($value["cost_measure"],"Percent") === 0){
            //$number .= getPercentOfNumber($local,$value["cost_amount"])."<br>";
            $number = getPercentOfNumber($local,$value["cost_amount"]);
            //$numberText.= $value["cost_amount"]." %<br>";
            $numberText = $value["cost_amount"];
            //$numberName .= "cost_name ".$value["cost_name"]."<br>";
            $numberName = $value["cost_name"];

            //Insert calculated costs in DB
            if ($stmt = $conn_mysqli -> prepare("INSERT INTO calculations_cost (calculation_id, costs_id, user_id, time, original_number, amount, measure, calculated_cost, name) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)")) {
                $stmt -> bind_param("iiissssss", $calculation_id, $costs_id, $user_id, $create_time, $local, $numberText, $value['cost_measure'], $number, $numberName);
                $stmt -> execute();
                $stmt -> close();
            }
            $sql = "INSERT INTO calculations_cost (calculation_id, costs_id, user_id, time, original_number, amount, measure, calculated_cost, name) VALUES ($calculation_id, $costs_id, $user_id, $create_time, $local, $numberText, ".$value['cost_measure'].", $number, $numberName)";
            echo $sql."<br>";
            }
}
```

When I display my query to see what should be inserted, I get this result:

```
INSERT INTO calculations_cost (calculation_id, costs_id, user_id, time, original_number, amount, measure, calculated_cost, name) VALUES (190, 5, 10, 2017-02-06 14:17:58, 8060.9, 0.50, Percent, 40.3045, Trosak prijevoz)
INSERT INTO calculations_cost (calculation_id, costs_id, user_id, time, original_number, amount, measure, calculated_cost, name) VALUES (190, 5, 10, 2017-02-06 14:17:58, 8060.9, 0.00, Percent, 0, Carina)
INSERT INTO calculations_cost (calculation_id, costs_id, user_id, time, original_number, amount, measure, calculated_cost, name) VALUES (190, 5, 10, 2017-02-06 14:17:58, 8060.9, 0.15, Percent, 12.09135, Banka)
INSERT INTO calculations_cost (calculation_id, costs_id, user_id, time, original_number, amount, measure, calculated_cost, name) VALUES (190, 5, 10, 2017-02-06 14:17:58, 8060.9, 25.00, Percent, 2015.225, PDV)
```

In DB I get this result:

```
INSERT INTO calculations_cost (calculation_id, costs_id, user_id, time, original_number, amount, measure, calculated_cost, name) VALUES (190, 5, 10, 2017-02-06 14:17:58, 8060.9, 0.00, Percent, 0, Carina)
INSERT INTO calculations_cost (calculation_id, costs_id, user_id, time, original_number, amount, measure, calculated_cost, name) VALUES (190, 5, 10, 2017-02-06 14:17:58, 8060.9, 0.15, Percent, 12.09135, Banka)
INSERT INTO calculations_cost (calculation_id, costs_id, user_id, time, original_number, amount, measure, calculated_cost, name) VALUES (190, 5, 10, 2017-02-06 14:17:58, 8060.9, 25.00, Percent, 2015.225, PDV)
```

Why first record is not inserted in DB? I can't figure it out.

Comment: Maybe you have an error in the first insert, have you tried to print the error if it occurs; like this: `ìf (! $stmt->execute()) echo "error: " . $mysqli->error;`

Comment: No, there is no error. It's not inserting first record wihout any errors. I can't figure out why. There is nothing special about the first record that could throw an error.

Comment: Have you tried to execute these four inserts by hand in your database?

Comment: Yes, it went without any problems.

Comment: OK, I managed to get some error and it says this: Notice: Undefined offset: 9 in C:\wamp\www\pma\calculation\custom_based_method.php on line 177 What does it mean?